# Имитация нажатие клавиши

Tags: c#

Пишу бота для одной игры на C#.

В игре есть чат, и там нажатие клавиш отображается, но если зайти в настройки игры и имитировать нажатие там, то ничего не происходит, как и матче игры, персонаж никак не реагирует.

Но если запустить Java и использовать Robot из AWT, то всё работает. В качестве отправки имитации клавиш попробывал :

```
1. SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
2. SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
3. [DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam);
4. [DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);
```

Может быть есть еще варианты?

Comment: Не советую так делать если игра большая и имеет античит/антибот.

Answer (score 0):

Эмулировать клавиатуру и мышь можно с помощью [InputSimulator](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=inputsimulator)

Например: большая буква "H"

```
  InputSimulator.SimulateKeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.SHIFT);
  InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_H);
  InputSimulator.SimulateKeyUp(VirtualKeyCode.SHIFT);
```

Comment: Не работает, в чате печатает, а в настройках ничего не происходит.

Comment: Попробуй между нажатиями клавиш поставить паузы  Thread.Sleep(200);

Comment: Пример кода для newerwiter 
```static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            KeyboardSimulator ks = new KeyboardSimulator();
            MouseSimulator ms = new MouseSimulator();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            while (true)
            {
                ks.KeyDown(DirectInputKeyCode.DIK_1);
                Thread.Sleep(50);
                ms.LeftButtonClick();
                Thread.Sleep(50);
                ks.KeyUp(DirectInputKeyCode.DIK_1);
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
        }```

Comment: это код на Java. На ней знаю как сделать, мне вот именно на C# надо. Можно конечно написать .Jar и его запускать из C#, но тут всё равно требуется ~ 150 - 200мб таскать, либо чтобы она была установлена.